# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in Qt5 application

Tags: qt, qt5

I have a Qt5 application that runs fine in the qtcreator, but if I try to run in by the executable created through terminal I get

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I've tried in debug mode in Qt but no errors.

Comment: On Linux? Check /var/log/syslog to see if it reports it in there.

Comment: on ubuntu 13.10 64 bits

Comment: Build with debug information, and run in a debugger.

Comment: Try with commandline gdb

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a program crashes when run outside of a debugger, but doesn't crash when run inside the debugger, it might be a sign that you are using uninitialized data. More specifically, an uninitialized pointer.

Debuggers generally clears all data, including local variables. That means that e.g. a pointer will be `NULL` when run in the debugger. But if you don't initialize some local variable, its contents will be indeterminate when run outside of the debugger, and your check against `NULL` will say "this is not NULL, please continue", and you will reference this uninitialized pointer and enter the territory of undefined behavior.

You need to go through all local variables, especially pointers, and make sure you initialize them before using them.