# Qt deployment error on linux

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, deployment, segmentation-fault

I tried to deploy a test Qt program on ubuntu following http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html. But when i run the program on another ubuntu machine (without Qt). It keep give error: Segmentation fault (core dumped).
I tried both staticly and dynamicly complied, but all give me the error.
The test code is simple and will show a small window.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<QApplication>
#include<QMainWindow>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv){
  QApplication app(argc,argv);
  QMainWindow *win=new QMainWindow();
  win->show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

The .pro file

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = test
QT += widgets
INCLUDEPATH += .
# Input
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

after static qmake complie with comand:

```
$/usr/local/Qt5.8.0/5.8/Src/qtbase/bin/qmake -config release
$make
```

i got the test program.

i tried to copy all the related library with a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh  
exe="test"  
des="."  
deplist=$(ldd $exe | awk  '{if (match($3,"/")){ printf("%s "),$3 } }')  
cp $deplist $des
```

and i got many related library files like:
libc.so.6      libfontconfig.so.1  libicudata.so.55             libnvidia-tls.so.340.102  libstdc++.so.6          libXau.so.6          libxcb-sync.so.1 and so on.

Then i set up a run-program script test.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
appname=`basename $0 | sed s,\.sh$,,`
dirname=`dirname $0`
tmp="${dirname#?}"
if [ "${dirname%$tmp}" != "/" ]; then
dirname=$PWD/$dirname
fi
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$dirname
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
$dirname/$appname "$@"
```

when running the script test.sh, it is successful on the ubuntu Qt machine.
But when i copy all the script and library files and run it on another no Qt ubuntu machine, it simply give me "Segmentation fault"

I dont know what causes the problem. Is is the library files like libc.so.6 or any other steps i missed.
Really appreciate your help.

Comment: If you are going to work in linux I recommend to use libraries in your compilation, or a better option if you are going to work in ubuntu is to create a .deb, in it you must configure the dependencies, then you can install your program with apt-get, this Will be in charge of obtaining the dependencies.

Comment: What do you get when you run: `ldd your_executable`

Comment: I'm not entirely certain what your question is but I refer you here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199873/segmentation-fault-core-dumped-in-qt5-application there are multiple threads with this question. In regard to running a program on a system without qt. No it won't just run as you need the appropriate libraries/dlls included. That's assuming you're using any part of the qt API. If you create a project in pure c++ which you haven't based on your code you could. It sounds like you're not including all the required files. Simple dynamic solution is place them in the output directory

Comment: Do not copy binaries. Ever. Either copy source and recompile, or package your binaries properly. Every other way will lead to random bugs, unmaintainable target and most probably corrupting the system into which you dump random binary objects, perhaps even overwriting some crucial system files if you do it in unlucky places.

Comment: Please tell, Why would you expect a Qt program to run on a machine where Qt is not installed properly?